# sum value of two different dictionaries which is having same key

Tags: python

i am having two dictionaries

```
first = {'id': 1, 'age': 23}
second = {'id': 4, 'out': 100}
```

I want output dictionary as

```
{'id': 5, 'age': 23, 'out':100}
```

I tried

```
>>> dict(first.items() + second.items())
{'age': 23, 'id': 4, 'out': 100}
```

but i am getting id as 4 but i want to it to be 5 .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

first = Counter({'id': 1, 'age': 23})
second = Counter({'id': 4, 'out': 100})

first_plus_second = first + second
print first_plus_second
```

Output:

```
Counter({'out': 100, 'age': 23, 'id': 5})
```

And if you need the result as a true `dict`, just use `dict(first_plus_second)`:

```
>>> print dict(first_plus_second)
{'age': 23, 'id': 5, 'out': 100}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add values from the second to the first, you can do it like this:

```
first = {'id': 1, 'age': 23}
second = {'id': 4, 'out': 100}

for k in second:
    if k in first:
        first[k] += second[k]
    else:
        first[k] = second[k]
print first
```

The above will output:

```
{'age': 23, 'id': 5, 'out': 100}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply update the `'id'` key afterwards:

```
result = dict(first.items() + second.items())
result['id'] = first['id'] + second['id']
```

Comment: thanks for your answer . if we do not know which key is same in all dictionary like there is very big dictinary . ?? thanks